# How can I have git not change file permissions?

Tags: git, lamp

I just verified that Git is opening up my file permissions when I push to remote server such that I have to do:

```
fixPerm() {
    cd ~/root
    find .  -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    cd stack_lamp
    find .  -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
}
```

As it tries to change files to 664 and folders to 775.

It is a hard bug to catch b.c. it does it only after you modify a file and it does not show up till it is on the server.

Thanks

Comment: What is the specific sequence of commands you have to run to cause this problem?

Comment: What is the output of the `umask` command?

Comment: There is no bug here. On Unix-like systems there is a functionality called `umask` that tells what permissions to **not** set when a file or directory is created. The usual value for `umask` is either `022` or `002`. You probably have `022` on your computer and it is `002` on the remote server. Git is not guilty at all. Your entire script can be replaced by `umask 022` in `.profile` on your account on the server.

Comment: mostly by defaulf umsak is 002